# count and get all records in mysqli/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I try count and get all records that `name = "john"`

I try this:

```
SELECT * COUNT(id) count FROM profile WHERE name = 'john'
```

But I got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'COUNT(id) count FROM profile WHERE name = 'john'' at line 1

what is the wrong?

Comment: Do you really need the count in each row? Have you considered fetching all the records with simple `SELECT * FROM profile WHERE name = 'john'` and then just getting the number of matched rows?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all *records* along with a total count, then you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(id) 
           FROM profile 
           WHERE name = 'john') as count
FROM profile 
WHERE name = 'john'
```

This query will return all records of `profile` having `name = 'john'`. For each record returned, the count of total records (having `name = 'john'`) will also be selected.

Answer (score 0):

For all record with count use inner query :-

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM profile 
WHERE name = 'john') as count
FROM profile 
WHERE name = 'john'
```

Comment: The first query is invalid. You can't mix aggregate functions with columns (*) like that without a GROUP BY.